# count number of identical elements in two arrays in linq

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I have 2 string arrays:

```
A1: {"aa","bb","cc","dd","ee"}
A2: {"cc","dd,"ee","bla","blu"}
```

how do I count the number of identical elements between `A1` and `A2` (in this case 3)?

Comment: What do you want to happen if there are duplicates in one of the arrays?

Comment: I want them to count as 1 match

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The shortest would probably be this:

```
A1.Intersect(A2).Count()
```

Comment: This is 3 characters shorter. A1.Count(A2.Contains) :) (I would still prefer your solution though)

Comment: @BlueVoodoo does the `Count Contains` approach do the right thing in the presence of duplicates? (see asker's clarifying comment)

Comment: @BlueVoodoo, for interest's sake,  a1.Count(a2.Contains); wins with 00:00:05.7862636!

Comment: @ericosg - That is actually quite interesting. Good to know.

Comment: @ericosg This may change depending on the size of the lists. Contains does a linear search (for every time through Count's loop); I suspect Intersect does something more clever.

Comment: `Intersect` does the following: put all elements of the first collection into a `Set`; then, iterate the second collection, trying to `Remove` every element from the set, and if `Remove` returned `true` (i.e. the element was present and removed), `yield return` that element. So it's partially lazy, which probably accounts for the perf difference with doing the same thing directly.

Answer (score 2):

The below works well and may produce higher performance when using lists:

```
List<string> a1 = new List<string>() { "aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee" };
List<string> a2 = new List<string>() { "cc", "dd", "ee", "bla", "blu" };

a1.Count(match => a2.Contains(match));
```

or (thanks @BlueVoodoo) a shorter solution that performs only slightly faster:

```
a1.Count(a2.Contains);
```

But these solutions count duplicates also, thus one could use:

```
HashSet<string> a1 = new HashSet<string>() { "aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee" };
HashSet<string> a2 = new HashSet<string>() { "cc", "dd", "ee", "bla", "blu" };
```

Which avoids duplicates since a HashSet keeps only a unique sequence.

After benchmarking the above, HashSet with a1.Count(a2.Contains); provides the fastest solution, even with the overhead of constructing the HashSet.

Comment: No need to put them in lists as you can do A1.Count(A2.Contains) directly on the arrays (I would still go for Pavel's intersect though).

Comment: For interest's sake, this solution runs faster than Intersect()

Comment: Further interest's sake some benchmarks:
at 10000000 iterations, Intersect vs Linq and Lambda:
with lists: 00:00:09.9623558 vs 00:00:06.2140126
with arrays: 00:00:09.5918331 vs 00:00:48.9175518

naturally, linq keeps creating IEnumerable objects from the arrays, producing overhead, but once all lists it's actually faster!

Comment: 5 minutes after you posted this, asker clarified the required behaviour in the presence of duplicates. You might want to revise your answer...

Answer (score 2):

```
int[] id1 = { 44, 26, 92, 30, 71, 38 };
int[] id2 = { 39, 59, 83, 47, 26, 4, 30 };

id1.Intersect(id2).Count();
```

Answer (score 1):

Following code should do the trick

```
        var A1 = new[] { "aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee"};
        var A2 = new[] { "cc", "dd", "ee", "bla", "blu" };

        var query = from one in A1
                    join two in A2 on one equals two
                    select one;
        var result = query.ToArray();//this should have { "cc", "dd", "ee" }
```